# How to delete an entire [AnyObject] array retrieved with a `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Does anyone know if its possible to delete an entire [AnyObject]  array retrieved with a `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` query?

The code bellow deletes one array item per time. But not all of them at once.

Have tried `comments?.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)` but compiler gives me an error: **Immutable value of type '[AnyObject]' only has mutating members named remove all**

`getObjectInBackgroundWithId` does not work as it only gets one object per time.

Quite stuck here... didn't find anything around about removing the whole array.

```
println("QUERY - DELETE COMMENTS")

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Comments")
    var post = currentObject
    query.whereKey("bellongsToPost", equalTo: post)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (comments: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        for comment in comments! as [AnyObject]
        {
           comment.deleteInBackground()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
PFObject.deleteAll(comments)
```

Obviously you need to unwrap comments, and do try catch if using Swift 2